# Extract data from a large string to table using SQL

Tags: sql

I'm trying to extract data strings from a long string using SQL query.

The string

```
"'35522':{'item_id':'35522','sku':'deded','RowTotal':37.5,'qty':2"
```

I am trying to create a loop query that extracts data from the string.
The desired output is a table with columns (item_id, sku, RowTotal, qty) and each line will be extracted from the string above in the relevant column.

I'm trying to create a function that will do that but currently I'm not close. Can you please assist me with ideas?

This is my code so far:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(4000) = 
'{:{item_id:35522,sku:deep-line-elixir,RowTotal:37.5,qty:2},
:{item_id:35527,sku:self-care-pamper-pack,RowTotal:158,qty:2},
:{item_id:35531,sku:neck-chest-rejuvenating-serum,RowTotal:21.87,qty:1},
:{item_id:35534,sku:pm-recovery-night-cream,RowTotal:23.75,qty:1},couponCode:,itemsQty:6}"'

DECLARE @b VARBINARY(4000) = CONVERT(varbinary(4000),@string)
DECLARE @StartPos int = 9
DECLARE @Len tinyint = 13

;WITH C (Orig, Startpos, Value) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        @b, @StartPos,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUBSTRING(@b, @StartPos, @Len))
    UNION ALL
    SELECT   
        @b, C.Startpos + @Len,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUBSTRING(@b, C.StartPos + @Len, @Len)) 
    FROM C
    WHERE C.Startpos + @Len < = LEN(@b)
)
SELECT C.Value 
FROM c 
WHERE c.value LIKE 'item%'
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The above code will not run on both. If any.)

Comment: Based on the syntax of `CONVERT` being `{data type}, {expression}` looks like T-SQL, not MySQL. Also, @jarlh, the above *does* run on SQL Server; it just doesn't return any results.

Comment: As well as tagging your question with the DBMS you are using, please update your question to say whether the string will always be valid JSON, or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach splits the data into rows using `STRING_SPLIT` before replacing the additional characters and using case expressions to match field values. The temporary table is used to generate a `row_num` which can be used to order values when generating the `group_num` used to group the related values across multiple rows into a single related row

```sql
DECLARE @SampleString VARCHAR(4000) = 
'{:{item_id:35522,sku:deep-line-elixir,RowTotal:37.5,qty:2},
:{item_id:35527,sku:self-care-pamper-pack,RowTotal:158,qty:2},
:{item_id:35531,sku:neck-chest-rejuvenating-serum,RowTotal:21.87,qty:1},
:{item_id:35534,sku:pm-recovery-night-cream,RowTotal:23.75,qty:1},couponCode:,itemsQty:6}"';

create table #temp_values (id int identity(1,1), value VARCHAR(200) );

insert into #temp_values (value) SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(@SampleString,'{',''),'}',''),',');


WITH split_data AS (
    SELECT id,value FROM #temp_values
),
extracted_data_raw AS (
SELECT 
     id as row_num,
     CASE 
         WHEN value LIKE '%item_id%' THEN 1
         WHEN value LIKE '%sku:%' THEN 2
         WHEN value LIKE '%RowTotal:%' THEN 3
         WHEN value LIKE '%qty:%' AND value NOT LIKE '%itemsQty%' THEN 4
     END as type_num,
     CASE 
         WHEN value LIKE '%item_id%' THEN TRIM(REPLACE(value,':item_id:','')) 
     END as item_id,
     CASE WHEN value LIKE '%sku:%' THEN TRIM(REPLACE(value,'sku:',''))  END as sku,
     CASE WHEN value LIKE '%RowTotal:%' THEN TRIM(REPLACE(value,'RowTotal:',''))   END as RowTotal,
     CASE WHEN value LIKE '%qty:%' AND value NOT LIKE '%itemsQty%' THEN TRIM(REPLACE(value,'qty:',''))   END as qty,
     value 
FROM split_data

)
,extracted_data_clean AS (
    SELECT 
        MAX(item_id) as item_id,
        MAX(sku) as sku,
        MAX(RowTotal) as RowTotal,
        MAX(qty) as qty
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type_num ORDER BY row_num) group_num,
            item_id,
            sku,
            RowTotal,
            qty
        FROM
            extracted_data_raw
        WHERE
            type_num IS NOT NULL
    ) t
    GROUP BY group_num

        
)
select *  from extracted_data_clean
```

Outputs:

| item_id | sku | RowTotal | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 35522 | deep-line-elixir | 37.5 | 2 |
| 35527 | self-care-pamper-pack | 158 | 2 |
| 35531 | neck-chest-rejuvenating-serum | 21.87 | 1 |
| 35534 | pm-recovery-night-cream | 23.75 | 1 |

[Working Demo DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5fd654bc9accc83e13877afec3d274d5)

#### Edit 1:

You also referenced `"'35522':{'item_id':'35522','sku':'deded','RowTotal':37.5,'qty':2"` in your question.  The following should work for both samples while also converting to respective data types:

```sql
DECLARE @SampleString VARCHAR(4000) = 
'{"35522":{item_id:35522,sku:deep-line-elixir,RowTotal:37.5,qty:2},
"35522":{item_id:35527,sku:self-care-pamper-pack,RowTotal:158,qty:2},
"35522":{item_id:35531,sku:neck-chest-rejuvenating-serum,RowTotal:21.87,qty:1},
"35522":{item_id:35534,sku:pm-recovery-night-cream,RowTotal:23.75,qty:1},couponCode:,itemsQty:6}"';

create table #temp_values (id int identity(1,1), value VARCHAR(200) );
insert into #temp_values (value) SELECT value FROM STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(@SampleString,'{',''),'}',''),',');
WITH split_data AS (
    SELECT id,value FROM #temp_values
),
extracted_data_raw AS (
SELECT 
     id as row_num,
     CASE 
         WHEN value LIKE '%item_id%' THEN 1
         WHEN value LIKE '%sku:%' THEN 2
         WHEN value LIKE '%RowTotal:%' THEN 3
         WHEN value LIKE '%qty:%' AND value NOT LIKE '%itemsQty%' THEN 4
     END as type_num,
     CASE 
         WHEN value LIKE '%item_id%' THEN CONVERT(INT,TRIM(
             REPLACE(SUBSTRING(
                  value,CHARINDEX('item_id',value),LEN(value)
             ),'item_id:','')
         )) 
     END as item_id,
     CASE WHEN value LIKE '%sku:%' THEN TRIM(REPLACE(value,'sku:',''))  END as sku,
     CASE WHEN value LIKE '%RowTotal:%' THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),TRIM(REPLACE(value,'RowTotal:','')))   END as RowTotal,
     CASE WHEN value LIKE '%qty:%' AND value NOT LIKE '%itemsQty%' THEN CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),TRIM(REPLACE(value,'qty:','')))   END as qty,
     value 
FROM split_data

)
,extracted_data_clean AS (
    SELECT 
        MAX(item_id) as item_id,
        MAX(sku) as sku,
        MAX(RowTotal) as RowTotal,
        MAX(qty) as qty
    FROM (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY type_num ORDER BY row_num) group_num,
            item_id,
            sku,
            RowTotal,
            qty
        FROM
            extracted_data_raw
        WHERE
            type_num IS NOT NULL
    ) t
    GROUP BY group_num
)
select *  from extracted_data_clean;

drop table #temp_values;
```

[Working Demo DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=404e3aff44bf4898f99f5ae6b320c4f2)
Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Look great! Can i ask what is the use of Max in the  extracted_data_clean  query?                                                
    "extracted_data_clean AS (
    SELECT 
        MAX(item_id) as item_id,
        MAX(sku) as sku,
        MAX(RowTotal) as RowTotal," ?

Comment: `extracted_data_clean` as CTE (common table expression) that is being used as staging area/alias/temporary subquery to do additional processing. In this case group the multiple rows generated by the STRING_SPLIT into complete records. Since I've used a group by to group these similar rows, i am using the MAX aggregate function to select the non-null values. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Really appreciate your assistance here. another question, how can i take a string that has '' inside into the SampleString?                                                                                        Example : {'3146144':{'item_id':'3146144','sku':'604072','RowTotal':995,'qty':1},'

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking and the comments are not ideal places for examples. Please create another question on stackoverflow with this question and sample data. You may mark the question as answered and upvote to help others with similar issues on stackoverflow to identify possible solutions.